# how to send java project with MySQL without the other person to install sql

Tags: java, mysql, send

I have completed an assignment on java with MySQL. How do I submit my project so that my teacher doesn't need to download and install MySQL but still run the program and connect to MySQL? Please, someone, help me. My deadline is in two days. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

You can host your database online and change the credentials in your code to connect to it. Here is an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEm0BN493sU) on how to do it using the free plan of Heroku

The new connection string must include the DNS or IP of the host and the port

```
jdbc:mysql://database-host:3306/dbname
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for the answer ^_^  I set up Heroku and everything and when i run the project on my pc with the MySQL connector jar file it runs but when i execute  the java project from computer that does not have MySQL i get No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://....